# How to create Gestures in my application?

Tags: android, gestures, android-gesture

I have submit button. When I do click or tap below a submit button, it should be able to recognize the gesture by programmatically in android. How could I do this?

Do I need to download anything based on Gestures? Else what should I do for this Gestures?

And, like a Gesture point- If I draw a line using Gesture concept or anything, gesture should perform its actions . After I draw a line, it should be able to open another screen. It must be able to display the last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information with regard to creating Gesture application at http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/working-with-gesture-api-in-android/

Comment: There's a simple translation of the original Android program (here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/apps/GestureBuilder), here: https://github.com/bmeike/GestureBuilder

Answer (score 2):

maybe you need this [android gestures](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/working-with-gesture-api-in-android/).

Comment: mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures); how to download the Gestures and what kinda gestures should i download then paste it under Resources ? Cud anyone tell me pleas?

Comment: http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/gesture+library Do i wanna download Gestures library from here ?